Binding of machine gun ammunition chain
I made the skeleton of a machine gun, and because I want to achieve the effect of the remaining bullets disappearing bit by bit after finishing the bullet in UE, the parent-child relationship of my Bullet14-1 can only be bound in this way. But I also want to create animations conveniently. So a spline IK was bound for him (using. 001 bone control). After binding, due to the parent-child relationship, I could only drag the entire elastic chain to move in the direction of the arrow (I canceled all scaling effects of splines on bones). But it's difficult to do animation this way, especially when the entire chain needs to be moved and rotated. How can we ensure that the tail of this bullet chain is not pulled away and does not deform when dragging the head? Or is there a better way to make this elastic chain controllable by the controller without being constrained by the head and tail of the bones?
